# Do I need to remove the flash hotshoe cap when taking pictures?

Tags: camera-basics, olympus

I just bought an Olympus Trip 35 and this is my first ever film camera. I went hiking yesterday and I took the camera to take shots. All of them were outdoors.

I was just wondering, the little cap that’s on top of the camera, covering the silver bit between the flash hotshoe rails, should that be taken out when taking pictures?

I’m very new to this, and it might sound stupid but I need to know.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the part you're referring to?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Olympus Trip 35]
*Original author: [Marc Lacoste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Marc_Lacoste). Used under CC-BY-2.5 license from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Olympus_Trip_35_2.jpg).*

If you are referring to the centre part of the camera, with the two rails and the silver dot surrounded by black plastic - no, you do not need to remove the cap. This is known as a *hotshoe*. Its purpose is to allow you to connect an external flash and allows the camera to trigger it.

Comment: I asked for clarification because the question could also describe the *lens cap* -- "top" is ambiguous (says someone who repairs nail guns for a living, and hears both ends referred to as "top" on a regular basis.

Comment: Yes it’s that one! Okay that explains everything, thank you so much!! I hope the pictures I took come out alright (fingers crossed)

Comment: @Henna No problem! Hope you enjoy the camera :)

Comment: There's no hotshoe "cap" shown in the picture. The question refers to something "covering the silver bit between the flash hotshoe rails".

Comment: @xiota You are correct. The photo I picked to put in my answer does not show a hotshoe cap. None of the photos I could find online included it. Likely the previous owner added it.